# Python3 GTK module gi not found

Tags: 16.04, python, gtk3

I followed the installation guide from:
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Then I tested the tutorial with "2.1. Simple Example"
https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#simple-example

but

`python3 ./my.py` fails like:

```
File "./my.py", line 1, in <module>
import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

So what can I do to get the import to succeed?

---

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: For those coming across this on fedora / redhat, `sudo dnf install python3-gobject` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the gi module for python3, like this:

```
sudo apt install python3-gi
```

You can also install it via pip3 (if pip3 is already installed), but be warned that the module name is different:

```
pip3 install --user pgi
```

You will need to change all of your references from **gi** to **pgi**.

Comment: Nope...

sudo apt install python3-gi -> is already installed as
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

says: 
sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0

 ***
pip3 install --user gi says:


ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gi (from versions: none)


ERROR: No matching distribution found for gi

Comment: Hmmm...I ran the example (I'm on bionic) and it worked as expected. What version of python3 does xenial use?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hmm...seems that their are 3.5 and 3.7 installed
/usr/local/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.7.2 and /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
....and forcing the 3.5.2 version works....